# Mozilla Thunderbird will not configure my email address on setup

Tags: thunderbird

I am a recently new user to the Ubuntu os. Upon installation and organizing everything the way i prefer, i stumbled across a problem with setting up mozilla thunderbird. When attempting to connect my gmail account, thunderbird does not register my email and correct password for some reason. I receive a message saying that my account cannot be configured due to an incorrect username or password. Even though my information is correct it will not proceed with the initial setup. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

There should be a button called "manual setup" or similar.
Click on this and enter your Gmail settings manually using the settings from https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&rd=1#ts=1665018,1665141,2769074

Additionally goto this link for recommended Thunderbird settings for Gmail : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78892?hl=en